# Postgresql syntax error when I copy table to csv

Tags: greenplum

My problem is related to the `COPY` command natively supported by postgres.

I read the official `COPY` documentation already.
I receive the following error:

```
db=> COPY t_abnormal_0  TO './myfile.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER TRUE, FORCE_QUOTE *);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: COPY t_abnormal_0  TO './myfile.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADE...
```

This works:

```
db=> \copy t_abnormal_0 to 't_abnormal_0.csv' WITH  DELIMITER '$' QUOTE '"' NULL AS '' CSV;
```

It seems that it can't recognize `FORCE_QUOTE`. I tried to add `FORCE_QUOTE` after the above.

```
db=> \copy t_abnormal_0 to 't_abnormal_0.csv' WITH  DELIMITER '$' QUOTE '"' NULL AS '' FORCE_QUOTE * CSV;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FORCE_QUOTE"
LINE 1: ...O STDOUT WITH  DELIMITER '$' QUOTE '"' NULL AS '' FORCE_QUOT...
```

I tried many different formats but couldn't get it to work.

The version of `postgres` is `9.2.24`

I check the version by `psql -V` . Besides, Actually it's a greenplum database. I'm sure if it's the same as postgres.
I suspect the version is older than 9.0, cause it can't detect FORCE_QUOT at all.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, but are you **sure** your first line does not work? This one: `COPY t_abnormal_0  TO './myfile.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER TRUE, FORCE_QUOTE *);` I checked it on 9.6 and it works well and i see no reason why it would be different, docs look almost the same.

Comment: @jbet Hi jbet. yes it works. I think the real version is about 8.0 , as it can't detect force_quote but detect force quote instead.  I check version by psql -V . Actually it's greenplum db.

Comment: `psql -V` is the version of psql (the client software), not PostgreSQL. Pleas check the server version with `SELECT version();`

Comment: @jbet So that is what  it is. Thanks for your notice.

Comment: You should use external tables with Greenplum because it will be a lot faster than COPY.  You should also use the correct version of psql.

Comment: This question has already been answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38210885/5368565